# Ruby and JRuby on the same Windows 7 machine

Tags: ruby, concurrency, jruby

Can I have Ruby and JRuby on the same Windows 7 machine without running into problems?

As I know both of them are tending to be registered in PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think pik might allow this:
https://github.com/vertiginous/pik

If that doesn't work you might want to look at running a linux instance inside a virtual machine and using rvm or rbenv.